# An Image Button navigate to another site html/css

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<a href="index2.html">
    <input type="image" class="button" value="">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
  background:url(example.jpg) no-repeat;
  cursor:-webkit-grab;
  border: none;
}
```

What should happen is that it display an image and when I click on, it will navigate to another this site `index2.html`. It worked with another image but it had an annoying border but after I changed the image it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an input type button, simply use img...

html:

```
<a href="index2.html">
  <img src="example.jpg" />
</a>
```

css:

```
a img {
  border: none;
  cursor: grab;
}
```